# Two cells same input in excel

Tags: excel, linker, cells

I am searching for a solution in excel. My goal is to enter a value in two different sheets but this value is the same in condition that if we change a value in any of these two sheets it will change automatically in the second one. So I can't use the **=(reference to the cell)** because it will create the link in one way.

Hope to find a solution.

Comment: You will need a macro or VBA to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the trick. If I change the value of cell A1 in Sheet1, the value of cell A1 in Sheet2 is set be equal to that of A1 in Sheet1 and vice versa.

Past this code into Sheet1 in the VBA Editor. Then copy this code and also past this into Sheet2 - change "Sheet2" into "Sheet1" in the code (on line 15)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Changed As Range
Dim vNew As String

Set Changed = Range("A1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


If Not Intersect(Target, Changed) Is Nothing Then
    vNew = Target.Value

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = vNew

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Set Changed = Nothing

End Sub
```